# Proper way to remove unwanted subview and dispose it in Monotouch

Tags: garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, dispose, subview

I have a class derived from UIControl called MyObject and I also have a List that holds several objects on MyObject type.

All these objects are added as SubViews in ViewDidLoad overridden method of UIViewController before calling base.ViewDidLoad (); (I don't know if this is important).

The thing is that at certain periods I want to remove several objects because I don't need them anymore. Here is what steps I take:
- First of all I remove that object from my generic list collection
- Then I remove it from view using RemoveFromSuperview() method.
At this point everything works well, but I also want to get rid of it from memory because I don't need it anymore and I also need to add some more objects so I have to free some memory. So I call Dispose() method on that object.

As soon as I do it I get a nasty exception:

```
Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_RectangleF (intptr,intptr,System.Drawing.RectangleF) <IL 0x00025, 0xffffffff>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.set_Frame (System.Drawing.RectangleF) [0x00021] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:1179
at BubbleBuster.Lib.UI.Gameplay.Bubble.Update (System.Drawing.RectangleF) [0x001a2] in /Development/Helix/iOS/BubbleBuster/BubbleBusterSolution/BubbleBusterApp/Lib/UI/Gameplay/Bubble.cs:141
at BubbleBuster.Lib.UI.Gameplay.BubbleCollection/<Update>c__AnonStorey2.<>m__4 (BubbleBuster.Lib.UI.Gameplay.Bubble) [0x00014] in /Development/Helix/iOS/BubbleBuster/BubbleBusterSolution/BubbleBusterApp/Lib/UI/Gameplay/BubbleCollection.cs:21
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach (System.Action`1<T>) [0x00018] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:360
at BubbleBuster.Lib.UI.Gameplay.BubbleCollection.Update (System.Drawing.RectangleF) [0x00014] in /Development/Helix/iOS/BubbleBuster/BubbleBusterSolution/BubbleBusterApp/Lib/UI/Gameplay/BubbleCollection.cs:19
at BubbleBuster.Lib.UI.Screens.WelcomeScreen.<UpdateTime_Elapsed>m__1 () [0x00000] in /Development/Helix/iOS/BubbleBuster/BubbleBusterSolution/BubbleBusterApp/Lib/UI/Screens/WelcomeScreen.cs:44
at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSAction.cs:48
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0004e, 0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>

Thread started: 
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
at BubbleBuster.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Development/Helix/iOS/BubbleBuster/BubbleBusterSolution/BubbleBusterApp/Main.cs:17
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

0   BubbleBusterApp                     0x0009094c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   BubbleBusterApp                     0x00005cd8 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9923959b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   ???                                 0x0e2662b8 0x0 + 237396664
5   ???                                 0x0e2661dc 0x0 + 237396444
6   ???                                 0x0e2651c6 0x0 + 237392326
7   ???                                 0x0e269920 0x0 + 237410592
8   ???                                 0x0e24f8e2 0x0 + 237304034
9   ???                                 0x0e2697e4 0x0 + 237410276
10  ???                                 0x0e269678 0x0 + 237409912
11  ???                                 0x0e2695e0 0x0 + 237409760
12  ???                                 0x09fe9a90 0x0 + 167680656
13  BubbleBusterApp                     0x0000a042 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
14  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00169f4e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
15  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00206748 monotouch_trampoline + 3416
16  CoreFoundation                      0x011d6e42 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
17  Foundation                          0x017509df __NSThreadPerformPerform + 254
18  CoreFoundation                      0x011a994f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0110cb43 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0110c424 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0110bd84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0110bc9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  GraphicsServices                    0x047c47d8 GSEventRunModal + 190
24  GraphicsServices                    0x047c488a GSEventRun + 103
25  UIKit                               0x02258626 UIApplicationMain + 1163
26  ???                                 0x0d7c4a05 0x0 + 226249221
27  ???                                 0x0d53cf18 0x0 + 223596312
28  ???                                 0x0d53cc10 0x0 + 223595536
29  ???                                 0x0d53cd66 0x0 + 223595878
30  BubbleBusterApp                     0x0000a042 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
31  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00169f4e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
32  BubbleBusterApp                     0x0016e034 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
33  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00173455 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
34  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00067245 mono_jit_exec + 149
35  BubbleBusterApp                     0x002116a5 main + 2837
36  BubbleBusterApp                     0x00003095 start + 53

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: You should not need to manually call Dispose() on views. There are situations where _you_ maybe don't hold an obvious reference any more, but maybe something else internally does. GC will clear the removed view if you just set your variables that reference it to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

From here:

```
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.set_Frame (System.Drawing.RectangleF) [0x00021] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:1179
```

it looks like you're setting Frame on a view that has already been freed.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the view, set it's tag to 333 i.e. 
To dispose the view:
MyCreatedView.ViewWithTag(333).RemoveFromSuperview();

Where -MyCreatedView- is the parent view of the view you want to get rid of.